# Use gruntjs to deploy last commit via ftp

Tags: git, ftp, gruntjs

I am starting to rely on gruntjs in my workflow — using it to compile sass and compress js.

Seeing it's potential, I would also love to use grunt for deployment in this particular way:

- get files in the latest git commit
- connect to host via ftp
- transfer the files from the latest commit only

There are a few grunt ftp, git, and deployment plugins out there, but none that seem to do it in this way.

Is there are a way to accomplish this without developing a custom plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/) is made for this. Running `cap deploy` will deploy your site from a git repository and only change the files that the last commit changed. Previous versions are also kept on hand so if a commit introduces a breaking change, you can easily rollback to a previous, known to be working state.

I'd highly recommend that you use Capistrano, but if you want to use Grunt for this then there's [grunt-git-ftp](https://github.com/carlosmarte/grunt-git-ftp) which does all of what you mention. It's less powerful than Capistrano but easier to configure.

Comment: awesome, thanks for tip! Capistrano looks too advanced for me at this point, but this grunt plugin should do nicely